# If $A$ is block-diagonal with $B$ in its diagonal, can we write it as $A=B\otimes I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, kronecker-product

I have a block diagonal matrix A which has the same block B in its diagonal entries. Can we express A as a product of B*I, where I is an identity matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you mean, but I think that the matrix $A$ that you're describing has the form
$$
A = \pmatrix{
B & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & B & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & B}.
$$
If this is the case, then we can write $A = I \otimes B$ where $I$ is an identity matrix and $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Comment: Thank you so much. You got what I was trying to say!